# from C# how to detect is fiddler running

Tags: c#, winforms, fiddler

How to detect is fiddler running on the pc by c# code.
because I don't want fiddler to capture my application requests.

thanks.

Comment: https://www.delftstack.com/howto/csharp/csharp-check-if-process-is-running/

Comment: Note that Wireshark essentially performs the same function as Fiddler, and perhaps other programs as well.  A determined person could write their own Fiddler clone.

Comment: A dedicated person could use ARP spoofing on a second machine to make you route all of your traffic through them, and then intercept traffic as they desire. Obviously SSL would be harder, but if they were in control of both machines then it would certainly be doable. What exactly are you trying to protect against here?

Comment: You are using the wrong approach. Instead you should better implement certificate/root CA pinning in your application. That will prevent request interception even if the proxy is not running on the same computer.